# Datastore Read/Write operations

Tags: google-app-engine

Just now, my application reached the free quota limit for the Datastore Read operation. `0.05 Million Opts`. With me just editing documents online with it.

So I came to realize that it is really important to deal with read/write op count. So how does the Datastore count the read/write ops? As per `put()` or `get()` of an `Entity` or as per `getProperty` or `setProperty` of an `Entity`?

Comment: Check out also the [Appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) for more detailed information regarding your operations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`put()`, `get()` and query `fetch()` operations will cause your data item to be transferred in whole from the data store to memory of your frontend instance. Once you have it in your memory, you will not pay for operations on its properties.

Note, however, that the charge for `put()` and `get()` might not be trivial. For example, in `put()` you do not pay for one write operation, but also for a bunch of index write operations (1/10th the charge for each IIRC) for each index associated with the written item.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Understanding_Write_Costs) explains the charges for write ops.